# How to remove cloud functions (slack-notification) from a specific cloud build trigger job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build

I have a cloud function which is configured for slack notification & also have two cloud build trigger against same repository (one is for push activity from git & another one for pull request activity from any branch).

Now when any jobs are getting triggered that cloud function will push the message in slack using pub/sub. But I just want the notification when any process failed or pass activity happen against push activity cloud build trigger, not for the pull request activity trigger. How do I remove the cloud functions for only pull request activity. Can I configure like this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: hey @Aniket ,  can you explain more how is your function is being triggered? and can you post your cloud builds files?

Answer (score 0):

To send the slack notification only according to the build status you can detect the type of the event and choose to send the slack notification or not.

On the `event.data` variable that you are receiving in the subscribe method you can read the variable `status` to check the status of the build, so you can send the slack notification only on SUCCESS or FAILURE status.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by adding a [substitution variable](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) (either in the build trigger config (UI), or the cloudbuild.yaml itself:

```
substitutions:
    _DISABLE_SLACK: 'true'
```

**Then in your slack webhook code:**

```
// don't send slack messages if we have _DISABLE_SLACK in `cloudbuild.yaml` file -- any value is accepted
if (build && build.substitutions && build.substitutions['_DISABLE_SLACK']) {
      return;
}
```

PS -- I also have another method where you want to disable slack messages for a build, BUT you still want errors... Can post that if you're interested :) 
[basically if build.status != 'WORKING', 'QUEUED', 'CANCELLED' && if build.buildTriggerId in [array], then we continue with slack message (overriding DISABLE_SLACK)]